# Android AndroidManifest.xml error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-manifest

today I'm trying to build my project, but build failed, here are logs:

```
    AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027appComponentFactory\u0027 in package \u0027android\u0027","sources":[{"file":"xxxxx/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/xxxxx/debug/AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":34}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
    xxxxx/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/xxxxx/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:35: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
    Failed to execute aapt
    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
 ....
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:380)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
        ... 9 more
    :app:processxxxxxDebugResources FAILED
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processxxxxxDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt
```

but I didn't modified any codes, I found these codes should not in AndroidManifest, because my project compileSDKVersion is 26, not the latest 28, I have no idea face to the problem, please help me, thanks!

Comment: show build.gradle, AndroidManifest files

Comment: Can you please post your manifest file over here

Comment: Did you use `appComponentFactory` in your manifest? This happened to me too but that wasn't the issue.